# ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Пытаюсь установить pycaret. При вызове from pycaret.classification import *
Выбивает ошибку
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2.
При импорте Jinja2 также ничего не работает. Объясните в чем проблема
Код ниже

```
!pip install pycaret
!pip install Jinja2
from pycaret.classification import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run this:  pip install Jinja2==3.1.2
and check other librarian versions:
https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык